# How would I initialize a String in a separate method from the main method?

Tags: java, methods, initialization

I want the user to enter a lower case b and the program recognizes that the b is lower case, and switch it to an upper case B. Since you cannot edit Strings during run time, how can I use a separate method from the main method in order to assign "name" to "name2". Once I try to print out "name2" after the method changes it, the compiler claims name2 hasn't been initialized even though it has been in a separate class.

I've tried initializing name2 as `name2="";` so the compiler doesn't say "name2 hasn't been initialized once I try to print name2 to console, however, you cannot redefine a String during run time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runner
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        String name2;


        TextArguments test1 = new TextArguments();

        System.out.println("Please enter a lower case b");
        name = input.nextLine();


        test1.test(name,name2);




        System.out.println(name2);
    }
}






public class TextArguments
{
    public String test(String name, String name2)
    {                               
        if(name == "b") 
        {
           name2 = "B";
        }
        else
        name2 = name;

        return name2;
    }
}
```

Expected results:

Enter a lowercase b.
b
B

Actual Results:

```
test1.test(name,name2); ("name2 might have no been initalized")
```

Comment: `if(name == "b") ` is not how you compare Strings in java

Comment: You can't do that, because Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: `return name.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parameters are inputs to a function. You want to return the string so you can get it back out of the function.

Use:

```
name2 = test1.test(name);
```

and:

```
public String test(String name)
{                    
    String name2;           
    if(name == "b") 
    {
         name2 = "B";
    // etc
```

Comment: I did that, however now when I run it, it returns name2 as b and not B.

Comment: @MattM Maybe that's because you shouldn't use `==` to compare strings.